# Jupyter notebook: activity forbidden

Tags: jupyter-notebook

While working on Jupyter Notebooks most actions are suddenly forbidden. 
Initially, I started my Jupyter app from Anaconda without any problems, some token was created in the terminal. Now I need to enter a password.

Worst is I can't save because somehow this is a forbidden action as well.
Same for changing the title of a notebook.

Clearing browser cache doesn't make a lasting difference (FireFox).
I reinstalled both Anaconda and Jupyter without apparent effect.

Any suggestion to remove all these restrictions? Thnx

Comment: Do you have cookies disabled in Firefox? If yes, enable them and try again.

Comment: Hmm, I changed cookie preferences to from 'remember history' to 'custom settings'. First try is successful. If it keeps working I'll let you know. Thnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jupyter notebooks use cookies to prevent XSRF](http://tornado.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-protection). Therefore, cookies must be enabled in the browser for notebooks to work correctly.