# jupyter notebook 'Forbidden' when making new Python file

Tags: python, macos, jupyter-notebook, terminal, jupyter

When attempting to create a python file in jupyter notebook I get Forbidden.

Im on the most recent version of jupyter, and python 3.11.4

how do I create a new python file?

I heard that it could be cache related, but I tried it on multiple browsers on cleared history

Comment: *I get Forbidden* - You mean a 403 forbidden error, or something else? Be specific!

Comment: I suspect by hearing it could related to browser caches and cookies, you meant [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41532441/jupyter-creating-notebook-failed-forbidden) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49256497/8508004)? Is a token involved in your case like some of the examples on there, too?

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the browser cache, including cookies, in Chrome

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).